# How to create a GraphQL typed SDK from a Typescript schema object?

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-js

I have a code-first GraphQL API in which the GraphQLSchema is created like so:

```
import { GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';
import { mutationType } from './mutation';
import { queryType } from './query';

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: queryType,
  mutation: mutationType,
});

export { schema };
```

I know how to generate a schema written in Schema Definition Language (SDL) with `printSchema(schema)`.

Now I need a SDK to provide to clients of my API. My problem is that I can't find any library for generating a typed SDK from the schema.

The libraries I find like [graphql-request](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request), [urql](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql) or [apollo-client](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client) make you write
the whole query without any type of syntax check.

```
import { gql, GraphQLClient } from 'graphql-request'

const query = gql`               //
  {                              //
    Movie(title: "Inception") {  // I can write whatever I want
      releaseDate                // here and no transpilation
      actors {                   // errors will appear.
        name                     // I have no autocompletion
      }                          // whatsoever.
    }                            //
  }                              //
`
const client = new GraphQLClient('https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/movies', { headers: {} })
client.request(query, variables).then((data) => console.log(data))
```

I want to be able to do something like `const client = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, schema, options);`. And then use it like so `await client.movie(title)({releaseDate: true, actors: {name: true}});`. Not necessarily with that syntax, but I hope this gets the idea across. If I write `rleaseDate` I just want a red line under it in my IDE and a transpilation error if I run `tsc`.

I've found [graphql-code-generator](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/) and I see that it can generate different things using the schema generated with `printSchema(schema)`. But for the typescript-graphql-request plugin that can generate the SDK I want, it appears I would need to write an operation.graphql file myself, which is the first thing I want to avoid. The API, as I said, is code-first and everything is in the schema I talk about in the start. I don't want a second source of truth in that operation.graphql file.

Does what I want exist?

Comment: This may not directly answer your question but look into https://the-guild.dev, they have a lot of projects aimed at making graphql development better and they are big on TypeScript. Their most recent blog post goes into custom errors in GraphQL and how they model it in TypeScript (complete with codegen from GraphQL's bespoke error format into real TypeScript errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright! So I found what I was looking for: [graphql-zeus](https://github.com/graphql-editor/graphql-zeus)

The command `zeus [path to SDL file] --typescript --node` generates an SDK I can provide to the clients that will use the API, and they can use the SDK like so:

```js
import { Chain } from "[SDK generated]";

Chain(`example.com/graphql`, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 00112233445566778899',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})('mutation')({
    createUser: [{
      username: newUsername,
      biography: newBio,
      picture: newPicture,
    },
  { id: true, username: true }]
})
  .catch(error => {
     // Do something
});
```

And `mutation`, the operation `createUser` and it's parameters are typed. Meaning I will get transpilation errors and the IDE will tell me what I can type in each field.